# Web Setup project, using Microsoft Visual Studio Installer projects, can't configure IIS deployment

Tags: c#, iis, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am building a Blazor server app project and I want to create an installer package using web setup project template from Microsoft installer projects.

I follow the steps from Microsoft on how to create and deploy the installer package https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/how-to-create-a-web-setup-for-your-published-web-service but I have no success.

[image]

[image]

[image]

When my app successfully deploys under my default web site on IIS as an application, I can't access it. When I am browsing to the newly published app on my IIS, I get an error

> HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

I enable directory browsing but I can only see the directory list. I want to see the full working Blazor app as I do when I manually deploy it to IIS by creating a new site and adding published files as my physical path.

[image]

Comment: Setup Project is a feature that comes back and forth for years, https://halfblood.pro/the-horrible-facts-on-visual-studio-setup-projects-45e66fe86d8d So expecting it to support latest bits like Blazor very well can be a challenge. You can report the issue on https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2022InstallerProjects&ssr=false#review-details and see if any assistance comes from there.

Comment: You need to make sure that your Blazor application's Web.config file is configured correctly and the <system.webServer> section needs to contain the correct handler mappings in order to handle the Blazor application's requests.